# Home Network - Port open, Firewall rule set - still unable to connect

Tags: networking, router, firewall, port-forwarding, port

I'm trying to setup a Minecraft Server for the Kids to play on and ensure no adults can interact with them.
I followed the tutorial on how to install it and it seems to be up and running.  I just can't connect to it.

I added a rule in Windows Firewall to allow port 19132 for the Server program.
I added a Rule to forward the port in my Edge Router 4 to the Server IP.
I check if the server is running with Netstat..

> C:\Users\rbarn>netstat -ano | find "19132"   UDP    0.0.0.0:19132
> *:*                                    7360

PID 7360 shows up as Windows Command Prompt (Bedrock Server)

When I try to connect using the Minecraft Client and point to the Server PC IP... 192.168.2.2:19132
It throws a timeout error.
When I check if the port is open using Port Checker, it times out also.

I'm going nuts.  Anyone have any Ideas short of joining me for diner and looking at the setup yourself?

Regards,
-NJ

Comment: Depends what's for dinner… ;))

Comment: so when you send data to 192.168.2.2:19132, you are doing it from within your LAN right? if that is the case, the issue is not with your router. it could be related to the local firewall on the server, or a problem with the server configuration. you'll want to get that working before you focus on making the server accessible over the Internet. you should be able to check out the windows event viewer to find messages about dropped packets if the issue is the firewall. for the server configuration, can you connect from a client running on the server itself?